# Declaring and initializing an array with pointers to arrays of arrays

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array, syntax

In the context of [this question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/11659/1677), I came up with the following code

```
typedef char Tuple[2];

Tuple test1[2] = {{1,2},{1,2}};
Tuple test2[3] = {{1,2},{1,2},{1,2}};
Tuple test3[4] = {{1,2},{1,2},{1,2},{1,5}};

Tuple* all[3]  = {test1, test2, test3};
```

to store pointers to arrays of arrays (2-tuples) in an initialized list. However, I failed to write equivalent code without using a `typedef`. What would the correct syntax for this look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char test1[2][2] = {{1, 2}, {1, 2}};
char test2[3][2] = {{1, 2}, {1, 2}, {1, 2}};
char test3[4][2] = {{1, 2}, {1, 2}, {1, 2}, {1, 5}};

char (*all[3])[2] = {test1, test2, test3};
```

Keep the typedef.